# populate combobox with data based on limit 1 db to another

Tags: combobox, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have 2 databases with product codes. The first one contains all available products for example: A,B,C,D,E,F,G etc

The second one contains only a few of those product codes, for example: A,E,F, etc

I would like my combobox to **only** show the items from the first database that **are not** in the second one.So in this exmaple : B,C,D,G etc

To show all the products from the first database I use : 
`products = @Unique(@DbColumn("product/products.nsf","Products",4)`

To show the products from the second database I use:
`product=@Unique(@DbLookup("product/colors.nsf","colors",value1,2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution :

```
var res = @Trim( @Replace(products, product, "") );
return res
```

res will only show the products that are not in product

(my usage : The user has to fill in some data per product. This way he will only see the products for which he still has to enter some data)

Answer (score 0):

The strength of SSJS is it's sitting on top of Java, which is very good for different collection types. I've blogged about this before http://www.intec.co.uk/mapping-java-collections/. Java Sets are designed to have no duplicate elements, and here's a good explanation of HashSet, LinkedHashSet and TreeSet which may be the most appropriate, depending on your requirement http://www.programcreek.com/2013/03/hashset-vs-treeset-vs-linkedhashset/. There are addAll and removeAll methods for all of these http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html, so you should be able to get a unique list quite easily.